# How to extend an existing Tree (with children, but no parents) to a doubly linked tree?

Tags: java, inheritance, data-structures, tree, subclass

I have a Tree<> class (legacy code, can't be changed), where each node consists of a label and a list of children:

```
public class Tree<L> implements Serializable, Comparable<Tree<L>>, Iterable<Tree<L>> {
    public Tree(L label, List<Tree<L>> children) {
        this.label = label;
        this.children = children;
    }
    ...
    // lots of methods, including the usual setters and getters
}
```

Now, I want to write a class `DoublyLinkedTree<L> extends Tree<L>` where, in addition to the children, each node also has a parent pointer. Normally, I wouldn't try to do this, but the base `Tree<>` class already contains a lot of very useful methods (e.g. `getSubtrees()`, `getSubtreesAtDepth()`) which I do not want to rewrite.

The trouble with extending the base class is that I want methods like `setChildren(List<DoublyLinkedTree<L>> children)`, which clash with the method `setChildren(List<Tree<L>> children)` in the base class.

Is there an elegant way to write a doubly-linked tree class extending the `Tree<>` class? The base class is very ill-suited for methods that involve *upward* searches like `getGrandParent()`, `getAllAncestorLabels()`, etc.

I am not expecting a readymade solution, but I feel that I am looking to solve the issue in a wrong way. Any guidance will be of immense help.

Comment: One approach may be to override `setChildren` (and all the other methods taking `Tree` that need to be aware of the new parent-relation). Also accept `List<Tree<L>>` and perform casts inside as required. The overridden method can always call the `super` version.

Comment: Both methods will have the same erasure, but neither overrides the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have `DoublyLinkedTree` extend `Tree`.

Define `setChildren` as `setChildren(List<? extends Tree<L>> children)`

Call `super.setChildren` from within that method. (You may need to do some casting here).

You won't be able to use polymorphism but you can now loop through the list of children and if they are an `instanceof DoublyLinkedTree` set their parent.